"id" component property is not defined by the component but every component should have it
I want to implement a new JSX interface to customize the behavior.
I use the following tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
        "jsx": "react",
        "jsxFactory": "createDOMElement"
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}


And this is the Main.tsx:
function createDOMElement(tagName: string | Function, props: any, ...children: any[]) {
    if (typeof tagName === 'function') {
        return tagName(props);
    }
    console.log(tagName, props, children);
    return tagName
}

function Button(data: { text: string }) {
    const button = (
        <button>Click me!</button>
    );
    console.log(button);
    return 'OK - from button'
}

export function Main() {
    const el = (
        <Button id="pippo" text="the text" />
    );

    console.log(el)

    return 'OK - from Main'
}

When run in the browser, I see in the console log:
button null ['Click me!']
Main.tsx:14 button
Main.tsx:23 OK - from button

So, it works as expected.
VSCode is unhappy about the "id" passed to Button.
Here is the error:
Type '{ id: string; text: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ text: string; }'.
  Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ text: string; }'.ts(2322)

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?
I would like to allow "id" property to every component.

<Button id="pippo" /> should be <Button text="pippo" />

sorry, I updated the question. the issue on "id" remains.

Please remove id="pippo"

Please read the title and the question: I would like to support the "id" property for every component I defined, even if the component doesn't specify it as a property.

Then add id to data: { text: string }; maybe use a reusable custom type whatsoever. I mean the error message is pretty clear.

As @pzaenger says, if you need to add an id property to the Button, then you need to modify the typings of the button, so function Button(data: { text: string }) { should be function Button(data: { id:string, text: string }) { instead. I guess that you should learn a bit more about TypeScript and JavaScript and their differences before diving in more, because the situation is pretty self-explanatory actually.

As ReactJS does, every component should allow id, className, and other stuff even if the component doesn't explicitly accept it. I would like to do the same.
This is a typescript issue, as the tags suggest, probably configuring the JSX namespace correctly. The question is related to that.

You are confusing a component with a component "content". React allows an id in each of the real HTML components (the ones that you are using inside your custom components, for example the <button>Click me!</button> one) because the HTML component has the id as a prop. If you add an id property to your custom component and you don't do anything with it (for example setting this id in the content of your custom component) then you are doing nothing. Still, in a component-oriented website is not usual to use the ID property. Are you maybe talking about the key property instead?

https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

How can I support "key" ? Can I support different property name as well?

If you want to add a different property, you need to add it to the props of the component, as we stated before with the id property. The key property is added by default by react.

JSX is a global namespace used for jsx.
React defines it here and here
To support id in every component, you must extend the IntrinsicAttributes interface with your key as follows:
declare global {
    namespace JSX {

        interface IntrinsicAttributes {
            id?: string
        }
    }
}

Now, every component can be instantiated with the id property even if the component doesn't have it in the signature.
